# Live migration of a jboss/wildfly container with CRIU failed

Tags: docker, wildfly

I've tried to live migrate a wildfly-container to another host [like described here](https://circleci.com/blog/checkpoint-and-restore-docker-container-with-criu/). The example with the np container works well. When I replace the example with a simple jboss/wildfly container, I just received this error when criu tries to restore the container on the other host :

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restore container <CONTAINER-ID>: criu failed: type NOTIFY errno 0
Error: failed to restore one or more containers
```

Because I didn't found a solution to this error, I've compiled the linux kernel like described on the [criu website](https://criu.org/Installation) and [here](http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/criu/experiment-to-suspend-and-resume-docker-container-with-criu/).

After that  `sudo criu check` prints:

```
Warn  (criu/libnetlink.c:54): ERROR -2 reported by netlink
Warn  (criu/libnetlink.c:54): ERROR -2 reported by netlink
Warn  (criu/sockets.c:711): The current kernel doesn't support packet_diag
Warn  (criu/libnetlink.c:54): ERROR -2 reported by netlink
Warn  (criu/sockets.c:721): The current kernel doesn't support netlink_diag
Info  prctl: PR_SET_MM_MAP_SIZE is not supported
Looks good.

criu --version
Version: 2.11

docker --version
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
```

Checkpoint/Restore for an example shell script [example](http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/criu/experiment-to-suspend-and-resume-docker-container-with-criu/) worked very well. But when I want to checkpoint a container

```
docker run -d --name looper busybox /bin/sh -c 'i=0; while true; do echo $i; i=$(expr $i + 1); sleep 1; done'
```

with

```
criu dump -t $PID --images-dir /tmp/looper
```

I receive this output

```
Error (criu/sockets.c:132): Diag module missing (-2)
Error (criu/sockets.c:132): Diag module missing (-2)
Error (criu/sockets.c:132): Diag module missing (-2)
Error (criu/mount.c:701): mnt: 87:./etc/hosts doesn't have a proper root mount
Error (criu/cr-dump.c:1641): Dumping FAILED.`
```

I can't find some solutions with these errors. Is there any known solution to live migrate a wildfly-container?

Thanks in advance